# multiple Element.prototype not working

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
Element.prototype = {
    hasClass : function(className){
        return this.className.contains(className, ' ');
    },
    getId: function(){
        return this.id;
    }
};
```

individually if it works

```js
    String.prototype.contains = function(item, from){
        return this.indexOf(item, from) != -1;
    };

    Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className){
        return this.className.contains(className, ' ');
    };
    Element.prototype.getId = function() {
        return this.id;
    };

    document.body.innerHTML=document.getElementById('foo').hasClass('blah');
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="blah"></div>
```

*It is the first time I deal with `prototype`*

Comment: You are overwriting the prototype, not extending it.

Comment: Off topic, but your `hasClass` is a little messed up. The second argument to `contains` is being passed as the second argument to `.indexOf()`, which expects an index number, not a string. The `' '` you're passing is probably being converted to `0`. And you'll get false positives as well. `...hasClass("la"); // true`

Comment: what would be the best way to create something like described above?

Comment: You already answered the question: `individually if it works` you're replacing the entire prototype of Element with an object containing only 2 methods. I am not sure if JS allows you to replace the prototype of Element so the methods will not show up or if it does allow you to break Element.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are setting prototype to a new object.
If you are using jQuery or something similar, then you can do something like this:

```
$.extend(Element.prototype, {
    hasClass : function(className){
        return this.className.contains(className, ' ');
    },
    getId: function(){
        return this.id;
    }
});
```

That ought to work.

Comment: I always assign prototype properties one at a time (which `$.extend` or `_.extend` both do). The only time I directly assign to the prototype is when I'm using inheritance: `MyObj.prototype = new ParrentType();`

Comment: I need not use jquery

Comment: @Sukima you mean `Child.prototype=Object.create(Parent.prototype)` don't you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 it's bad to create an instance of Parent to set as the prototype of Child, the Parent constructor has likely some initialization to create instance specific members that have no business being on Child.prototype.

Comment: Yeah, still haven't left my ES3 days. Usually managed via `function Child() { Parent.call(this); }` and `Child.prototype = new Parent()`. But you are correct with ES5 and above `Object.create` is the better choice. I'm going to start looking into modifying my habit there.